# References for non-zero boundary value problem

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, parabolic-pde, hyperbolic-pde

I studied linear elliptic, parabolic and hyperbolic PDEs (boundary/initial value problem) in terms of existence, uniqueness and regularity. 
I studied always, following Evans book "PDE", the case with zero boundary value. I've tried to repeat some energy estimates with non zero boundary value and I got some results that i wanna check. 
Where could I find references for this kind of problems?

Thanks for the help,
Marco Menale

Answer (score 1):

The book by Demengel and Demengel has exactly what you seek.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult for me to check the details at the moment, but the book *Non-Homogeneous Boundary Value Problems and Applications* by Lions and Magenes might also be helpful, perhaps more so for elliptic problems.